# How do I center a div element with typed.js

Tags: javascript, typed.js

How do I center a div element with typed.js

```
<script>
    var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
      stringsElement: '#typed-strings'
    });
</script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { var typed = new Typed("#typed", { stringsElement:'#typed-strings', typeSpeed: 30, }); });
</script>

<br><br>

<div id="typed-strings">


<p>
text here</p>

</div>
<div id="typed"></div>
```

I tried to use css to center my div where the text is being typed:

```
#typed-strings {
  top: 50%;
left: 50%;
border: 4px solid #ecf0f1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to center the typed text inside the div:

```
#typed-strings {
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you're looking to center the div in the center of the screen:

```
#typed-strings {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```